# Как сделать подпись картинки в тг боте

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

```py
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from aiogram.types import ReplyKeyboardRemove, \
    ReplyKeyboardMarkup, KeyboardButton, \
    InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton

#api ключ бота
bot = Bot(token='токен')
#Диспетчер, будет обрабатывать сообщения
dp = Dispatcher(bot)
#Фото для бота
startphoto = open('images/start.jpg', 'rb')

@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def start(message: types.Message):
    markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    catalog = InlineKeyboardButton("КАТАЛОГ", callback_data='catalog')
    markup.add(catalog)
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id,startphoto, caption='Привет!✋\nЭтот чат-бот удивит тебя низкими ценами на подписки популярных сервисов!\nНапример подписка на дискорд "нитро" у нас стоит 260₽, вместо 804₽', reply_markup=markup)


executor.start_polling(dp)
```

Я нашёл как это делать, всё верно скопировал , но не работает
Ошибка:

```
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id,startphoto, caption='Привет!✋\nЭтот чат-бот удивит тебя низкими ценами на подписки популярных сервисов!\nНапример подписка на дискорд "нитро" у нас стоит 260₽, вместо 804₽', reply_markup=markup)
TypeError: Bot.send_message() got an unexpected keyword argument 'caption'
```

Comment: попробуйте убрать `caption=` в вызове функции

Comment: нет.))) вам нужно использовать для этого не `bot.send_message`, а `bot.send_photo`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно использовать [`bot.send_photo`](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/dev-3.x/api/methods/send_photo.html), потому что `bot.send_message` принимает только текст.

```py
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from aiogram.types import ReplyKeyboardRemove, \
    ReplyKeyboardMarkup, KeyboardButton, \
    InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton

#api ключ бота
bot = Bot(token='токен')
#Диспетчер, будет обрабатывать сообщения
dp = Dispatcher(bot)
#Фото для бота
startphoto = open('images/start.jpg', 'rb')

@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def start(message: types.Message):
    markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    catalog = InlineKeyboardButton("КАТАЛОГ", callback_data='catalog')
    markup.add(catalog)
    await bot.send_photo(message.chat.id,startphoto, caption='Привет!✋\nЭтот чат-бот удивит тебя низкими ценами на подписки популярных сервисов!\nНапример подписка на дискорд "нитро" у нас стоит 260₽, вместо 804₽', reply_markup=markup)



executor.start_polling(dp)
```

Comment: @Игорь https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers